# PowerShell PKI Module (PSPKI) Submit-CertificateRequest without storing CSR in file

Tags: windows, powershell, pki, csr, certificate-authority

I am using the PowerShell PKI Module to manage my certificates on Enterprise ADCS. I have created a simple tool that is using PS scripts for better convenience and to save some time.

When issuing certificates, I am using the [Submit-CertificateRequest](https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/pspki/Submit-CertificateRequest/) command, which takes as an input CSR stored in the file through `-Path` parameter:

```bash
Submit-CertificateRequest -Path $csrFileName -CertificationAuthority $cca -Attribute "CertificateTemplate:$certificateTemplate"
```

This means that whenever I provide the CSR in the script, I need to store it first in the file, than use the command to issue certificate, and after that delete the file with the CSR. This is a complexity I would like to remove.

Is there any way how I can provide the CSR as input to the command without storing it in the file? The `-Path` parameter is required and I need somehow reference file that will be used as CSR to issue certificate. Can I avoid that? Is there a better way how I can submit requests without storing them in the file?

My primary interface is PowerShell, if this would be feasible with the current PSPKI commands, it would be great.

Comment: Where is the CSR coming from, if it's not a file?

Comment: It is coming as base64 encoded data or PEM as input from the user

Comment: I see.  I suppose you could wrap `Submit-CertificateRequest` in a function that creates a temp file, submits it as the CSR, then deletes it.  Unlike Linux-esque shells, I don't think you can pass a variable or string as a file into PowerShell without a temporary file.

Comment: that is what I would like to avoid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could emulate what `Submit-CertificateRequest` does, but it's probably longer than wrapping it in a function:

```
$req = "
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
"

$CertConfig = New-Object -ComObject CertificateAuthority.Config
$ConfigString = $CertConfig.GetConfig(1)
$CertRequest = New-Object -ComObject CertificateAuthority.Request
$Status = $CertRequest.Submit(0,$req,"CertificateTemplate:WebServer",$ConfigString)
```

Note that the above was blatantly plagiarised from the author of `Submit-CertificateRequest`'s [web page](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/introducing-to-certificate-enrollment-apis-part-3-certificate-request-submission-and-response-installation.aspx) (which was offline when I wrote this, so here is a [cached version](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:UKTgwoAH19MJ:https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/introducing-to-certificate-enrollment-apis-part-3-certificate-request-submission-and-response-installation.aspx&hl=en&gl=uk)).

The `GetConfig()` method takes a single argument:

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| CC_DEFAULTCONFIG 0x00000000 | Retrieves the default certification authority. |
| CC_UIPICKCONFIG 0x00000001 | Displays a user interface that allows the user to select a certification authority. |
| CC_FIRSTCONFIG 0x00000002 | Returns the first certification authority. |
| CC_LOCALACTIVECONFIG 0x00000004 | Retrieves the local certification authority if it is running. |
| CC_LOCALCONFIG 0x00000003 | Retrieves the local certification authority. |
| CC_UIPICKCONFIGSKIPLOCALCA 0x00000005 | Displays a user interface that allows the user to select a certification authority. The UI excludes any local certification authority. This exclusion is useful during subordinate certification authority certificate renewal when the subordinate certification authority certificate request is submitted to a certification authority other than the current certification authority. |

---

If you know your CA Config string beforehand, then you can simplify this into two lines:

```
$CertRequest = New-Object -ComObject CertificateAuthority.Request
$Status = $CertRequest.Submit(0,$req,"CertificateTemplate:WebServer","ca1.example.org\Example CA1")
```